# Need help writing compound linux query

Tags: linux

Trying to write my first compund linux query and running into some gaps in knowledge.

The idea is to find all the file that may be either .doc or .txt as well as search the contents for the text clown.

So I started off with searching from the root as such.

```
$find /
```

Then I added the wildcard for filename.'

```
$find / -name '*.doc'...uhh oh
```

First question. How do I specify or? Is it with pipe | or double pipe || or...? and do I need to repeat the -name parameter like this?

```
$find / -name '*.doc' || -name '*.txt'
```

Second ? do I add the grep for the string after / before...?

```
$find / -name '*.doc' || -name '*.txt' grep -H 'cat' {} \
```

Finally is there a place where I can validate syntax / run like SQLFiddle?

TIA

Comment: To find out more about a command and its arguments read the man page (type `man <command>`, e.g. `man find`.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Or' in find is `-o`

You have to specify the find type again though. So something like:

```
find / -name *.doc -o -name *.txt
```

You can simply put your grep command in front, so long as you encase your find command in backticks:

```
grep 'whatever' `find / -name *.doc -o -name *.txt`
```

There's a reasonably nice guide to find [here](http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/find.php)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
find / \( -name \*.doc -o -name \*.txt \) -exec grep clown {} \; -print
```

you specify or with `-o` within `\( \)`, you run `grep` in a `-exec` and you can validate the syntax in a bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(find ./ -name "*.txt" -print0 2>/dev/null ; find ./ -name "*.doc" -print0 2>/dev/null) | xargs -0 grep clown
```